# ConnectableObservable - why does Connect internally create a new subscription?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I was looking at the [source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts) of ConnectableObservable.

```
  connect(): Subscription {
    let connection = this._connection;
    if (!connection) {
      connection = this._connection = new Subscription();
      const subject = this.getSubject();
      connection.add(
        this.source.subscribe(
          new OperatorSubscriber(
            subject as any,
            //...

    return connection;
  }
```

Now I'm wondering why does the `Connect` method internally create a new `connection` subscription, if `this.source.subscribe` returns a subscription already - why not return that subscription from the `Connect` method instead? I'm aware that this has exactly the same effect, e.g. the subscription returned from the `this.source.subscribe` call gets added to the `connection` subscription and whenever `connection.unsubscribe()` is called both subscriptions get unsubscribed. The only reason I can think of is that currently the `this.source.subscribe` call returns a `Subscription`, but if it starts returning an object of a different type that would still get accepted by `Subscription.add` method, then we wouldn't have to change the return type of the `connect` method, which we would have to do if `Connect` returned the result of `this.source.subscribe` directly.

While I might not get a definite answer, anything that could justify that code would be useful.